# Fixed top and left menu with reponsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to know if is it possible to create a theme with css where we can fixed the top and the left, and in the same time the theme must be responsive.

Thank you

Comment: You can take a look at http://getbootstrap.com. This websites provides you basic templates responsive and non-responsive.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not asking for book or ressource, I'm asking for opinions, I just want to know if is it logical to do it or not.

Comment: Opinions are off-topic too.

Comment: so what is in-topic !!!

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own code just check out below Code snippet:-

```css
.main-container{position:absolute; top:0; left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#eee}
header{background:#aaa;height:100px;}
.second-row{width:100%;background:#999; height:calc(100% - 100px); height:-moz-calc(100% - 100px); height:-webkit-calc(100% - 100px); }
aside{width:200px;height:100%; background:#666;float:left;}
.right-blk{width:clac(100% - 200px); width:-moz-clac(100% - 200px); width:-webkit-clac(100% - 200px); height:100%; background:#ddd;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
  this is fixed header
  </header>
  <div class="second-row">
  <aside>
    this is fixed left block
  </aside>
    <div class="right-blk">
        <div><div class="lc"><h2 class="what"><span>What is Lorem Ipsum?</span></h2><p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div><div class="rc"><h2 class="why"><span>Why do we use it?</span></h2><p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p></div></div>
      <div><div class="lc"><h2 class="what"><span>What is Lorem Ipsum?</span></h2><p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div><div class="rc"><h2 class="why"><span>Why do we use it?</span></h2><p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my above snippet @dbyba

Comment: thank you for the example, so it's possible to do it :)

Comment: everything is possible @dbyba.